# How to include a \perp symbol in a ggplot2 annotation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols, annotate

I would like to put an annotation : E \perp c using `ggplot2` `annotate("text", label = ...)`.

I searched quite thorougly on the web but only managed to get a lone symbol using `annotate("text", label = "symbol('\136')", parse = T)`.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Not a solution, but relevant https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-May/130915.html

Comment: BTW, my table of LaTeX symbols says the glyph that appears with '\\136` could also be named `\bot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plotting code from help page:

```
 p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = gp, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean),
               colour = 'red', size = 3)
 p+geom_text( aes(x="b", y=-0.4, label = "E(y)*symbol('\\136')*b" ),
   parse = TRUE)
```

After getting this to work I was also able to get `annotate(text"...)` working:

```
p+annotate("text",  1, -0.4, label="E(y)*symbol('\\136')*b", parse=TRUE)
```

The tricks: to mix your quoting characters which you did but to also use plotmath syntax which I'm guessing you might not have used.

Edit: `*` is not a quoting character. If anything, it should be called a linking character. In plotmath syntax every "atom" or function call needs to be separated from (or "linked-to" depending on how you view it) the adjoining atoms/functions. You can do this with `*` (the no-space separator/linker), `~` (the spacing separator/linker), or any of the dyadic operators in the plotmath vocabulary, examples including `+` , `-`, `==`, `!=`.

Comment: Thank you ! This seems to do the trick. I did not know * was a quoting character.

Comment: See above. I don't think you picked up the correct understanding of plotmath syntax from the example.

Comment: I see, I guess I need to study plotmath a little more in depth. Thank you very much for clarifying that !